# Creating a linked list of n length

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote [this working code](https://ideone.com/WDaLRP) to create a linked list of a given length and print each node's values.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //NULL
#include <stdio.h>  //printf

typedef struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node* next;
} node;

node* make_ll(int len){
    node* head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* cur = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cur->val = i;
        cur->next = (i < (len - 1)) ? malloc(sizeof(node)) : NULL;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return head;
}

void print_ll(node* head){
    node* cur = head;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("Node: %d @ %p\n", cur->val, cur);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    node* ll = make_ll(4);
    print_ll(ll);
    free(ll);
}
```

Output:

```
Node: 0 @ 0x81b010
Node: 1 @ 0x81b030
Node: 2 @ 0x81b050
Node: 3 @ 0x81b070
```

I'm wondering if there's a practical way to write `make_ll()` so that, rather than checking if we've reached the last desired node on every pass of the `for` loop and setting `cur->next` accordingly, as done here with line 14:

```c
cur->next = (i < (len - 1)) ? malloc(sizeof(node)) : NULL;
```

we can simply `malloc()` for each "next" node until the last, setting it equal to `NULL`.

I'm new to C, mostly influenced by Python, and the things I tried to no avail were the result of my ignorance of the languages' difference in scope rules. It would probably be noisy to try to reproduce them here.

Any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there's a practical way to write make_ll() ... we can simply malloc() for each "next" node until the last, setting it equal to NULL.

Use a temporary head node.  This also handles cases when `i <= 0` by returning `NULL`, unlike OP's code that leaves the head node uninitialized.

```
node* make_ll(int len){
  node head;  // Code only populates the next field.
  head.next = NULL;
  node* cur = &head;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cur->next = malloc(sizeof *(cur->next));
    assert(cur->next);
    cur = cur->next;
    cur->val = i;
    cur->next = NULL;
  }
  return head.next;
}
```

---

Other notes

Notice how the below `malloc()` size works without even knowing the type of the pointer.  This is less error prone and easier to maintain.

```
// some_pointer = malloc(sizeof(some_type));
some_pointer = malloc(sizeof *some_pointer);
```

Use matching type with the specifier to avoid undefined behavior: `void *` with `"%p"`.

```
printf("Node: %d @ %p\n", cur->val, (void *) cur);
```

Minor: When a function does not alter objects that are "pointed", consider using `const` to 1) indicate no change 2) allow passing a pointer to a constant linked list  (this is rare with linked lists)

```
void print_ll(const node* head) {
    const node* cur = head;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("Node: %d @ %p\n", cur->val, (const void *) cur);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answered the crux of my question and was instructive in a number of other ways. Thanks!

The result: https://ideone.com/f1EXmz

Answer (score 3):

## naked `malloc` calls

Note that `malloc()` simply allocates memory - you have no guarantees about what the newly allocated memory contains. For that reason it is better to write a function which both allocates and initializes an new object, i.e.:

```
node* newNode(int v) {
  node* p = (node*) malloc( sizeof(node) );
  // assume malloc never fails
  p->val = v;
  p->next = NULL;
  return p;
}
```

Now use `newNode()` where you are using `malloc()` directly.

## `make_ll`

First of all, does your `make_ll` work for len = 0?

For comparison, here is a recursive solution for `make_ll`:

```
node* make_ll(int len) {
  if (len <= 0) {
    return NULL;        // a list of length 0
  } else {
    node *tail = make_ll(len-1);
    node *head = newNode(len);
    head->next = tail;
    return head;
  }
}
```

And here is a way I would transform this into a loop which avoids double checking the exit condition:

```
node* make_ll(int len) {
  if (len <= 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  node* head = newNode(len);
  node* last = head;
  for (; len > 0; --len) {
    node* n = newNode(len);
    last->next = n;
    last = n; 
  }
  return head;
}
```

The idea is to keep track of the last node in the chain so you can update its `next` field when you create a new node.

Comment: Writing a function to create a new node is a good idea as it's reusable for
inserting into a list. If it's even desirable, I'll make it an exercise to
generalize `newNode()` to accept any struct and create a new node assigning values to its respective members.

Comment: "no guarantees the newly allocated memory contains. it is better to write a function which both allocates and initializes a new object"

How does allocating and initializing a new object within a function more adequately ensure what the newly allocated memory contains compared to doing so outside a function? Are you saying the allocated memory could already be populated? (cont'd next)

Comment: (cont'd)

From http://www.gidforums.com/t-9340.html:

"malloc() will fail if it can't allocate enough contiguous memory to satisfy the request."

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Small quibble: As noted by chux below*, I've read it's best not to
cast `malloc` in C, while it's expected in C++.

http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Type_safety

*http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104278/creating-a-linked-list-of-n-length/104318#104318

Comment: Hadn't thought of a recursive solution, creating from the tail node back to the head, connecting as you go. I'm unsure whether there's a practical adaptation applicable when tracking each iteration, as in my example.

Output of your first adaptation:
http://codepad.org/BO3gB1E7

Output of your second:
http://codepad.org/m5hsKppI

My undesirable fix for first:
http://codepad.org/S2OWTjYz

Thanks for all the instruction!

Comment: re: guarantees - after a malloc() you have no guarantees about what the new memory contains. You should always initialize newly allocated memory before using it. In your original code it is not clear that `cur->val` gets set after the `malloc()` call, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

## Format string mismatch

GCC warns me:

```
104278.c:23:29: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘node *’ {aka ‘struct Node *’} [-Wformat=]
         printf("Node: %d @ %p\n", cur->val, cur);
                            ~^               ~~~
```

You need to cast `cur` to the correct type when using it in `printf()`, because it's a varargs function.

## Memory leak

Valgrind reports:

```
==1612== 48 (16 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==1612==    at 0x48357BF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1612==    by 0x10919C: make_ll (104278.c:14)
==1612==    by 0x109227: main (104278.c:29)
```

That's because we only release the head node of the list; the other nodes are still allocated, but no longer reachable.  We need to go through the list and delete *all* the nodes:

```
void free_ll(node *head)
{
    while (head) {
        node *n = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(n);
    }
}
```

Use that in place of `free(ll)`.

## Const-correctness

The "print" function should be clear that it won't modify the list:

```
void print_ll(const node *head)
{
    const node *cur = head;
    while (cur) {
        printf("Node: %d @ %p\n", cur->val, (const void*)cur);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

## Don't assume that allocation will succeed

*Always* test the pointer returned from `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()` before using it.